# получить значение get

Tags: php, html, mysql

есть такой код

```
if (isSet($_GET["sub"]) AND isSet($_GET['limit']))
{
    $sub = $_GET["sub"];
    $limit=$_GET['limit'];
    $result28 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id_sub=$sub ORDER BY rand() LIMIT ".$limit ,$db);

    $myrow28 = mysql_fetch_array($result28);

    printf("<p><a href='test.php?sub=%s&limit=%2'><font size='2px'>%s</font></a><p /><font size='2px'>%i</font></a><p />",$myrow28["id"],$myrow28["name"]);
```

как сделать, чтобы в `href...limit=%2` записывалась переменная, которую можно вводить с интерфейса и она будет записываться в `$limit sql-запроса`?

Comment: ты в блокноте чтоли разрабатываешь? откуда функции `isSet`  взял?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php

Answer (score 0):

Не много не понял вопрос, но возможно нужно так

вместо

```
 printf("<p><a href='test.php?sub=%s&limit=%2'><font size='2px'>%s</font></a><p /><font size='2px'>%i</font></a><p />",$myrow28["id"],$myrow28["name"]);
```

вставить

```
echo '<p><a href="test.php?sub='.$limit.'"><font size="2px">'.$myrow28["id"].'</font></a><p/><font size="2px">'.$myrow28["name"].'</font></a><p/>';
```

Comment: limit и sub это разные значения, если в limit стоит 2, то все работает. вот задача - поставить вместо константы переменную

Comment: просто сделайте test.php?sub=%s&limit=$limit
на самом деле если вы берете код в двойные кавычки " то можно не делать конкатенацию.
"test.php?sub=%s&limit=$limit"
либо
"test.php?sub=%s&limit={$limit}"

Comment: а как ее передать в адресную строку так, чтобы она вводилась с клавиатуры пользователем?